# Why am I receiving Segmentation fault for extremely large inputs?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My question is to coding for a text editor where the operations

*
1-append

2-delete k characters from last

3-print nth character

4-undo

*

Input format is

*

The first line contains an integer,Q, denoting the number of operations.

Each line i of the Q subsequent lines (where 0<=i<=Q) defines an operation to be performed.

Each operation starts with a single integer, t (where t is either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4), denoting a type of operation as defined in the Problem Statement above.

If the operation requires an argument, t is followed by its space-separated argument.

For example, if t=1 and W="abcd" , line i will be 1 abcd.

*

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 10000

char stack[max],super[max][max];
int top=-1,btop=-1,supert=-1;
int bottom=1,qqq=0;

void push(char elem[])
{
    //top++;
    btop=top;
    int i=0;
    strcat(stack,elem);
    strcpy(super[++supert],stack);
}

void pop(int k)
{
    top=strlen(stack);
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        top--;
    }
    stack[top]='\0';
    /*int i=0;
    if(top==-1)
    {
        strcpy(stack,"");
    }
    else
    {
        i=top;
        while(i<btop)
        {
            i++;
            stack[i]='\0';
        }
    }*/
    strcpy(super[++supert],stack);
}

int main() 
{
    int tot,op;
    scanf("%d",&tot);
    int q=0;
    for(int i=0;i<tot;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:;
                char elem[max];
                scanf("%s",elem);
                push(elem);
                //printf("%s\n",stack);
            break;
            
            case 2:;
                int num;
                scanf("%d",&num);
                pop(num);
                //printf("%s\n",stack);
            break;
            
            case 3:;
                int k;
                qqq++;
                scanf("%d",&k);
                /*if(qqq%2==0)
                {
                    printf("%c\n",stack[k-3]);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c\n",stack[k-1]);
                }*/
                printf("%c\n",stack[k-1]);
                
            break;
            
            case 4:;
                supert=supert-1;
                strcpy(stack,super[supert]);
                q--;
                //printf("%s\n",stack);
            break;
        }
        q++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

For extremely large inputs(operations in the order of 10^5 or 10^6) I am getting segmentation fault
Also I could not increase the size of max because if I increase I am getting an error
Why is it so?

Comment: Please let us know what exactly an _"extremely large input"_ is. Anyway I suspect `char elem[max]; scanf("%s",elem);` here. if your input is a string longer than `max` you'll get into trouble.

Comment: Extremely large inputs in the since when the operations are around 10^5 or 10^6

Comment: And also I was not able to increase max more than what I have in my code if I increase then I get error

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put all relevant information _there_. Also show us an example of an input that triggers the problem. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky the input is very large I cannot paste it here

Comment: Run it with you debugger. The debugger will show you where exactly the segfault happens and then you can inspect the contents of variables etc. and find out what's going on. Or maybe you should just check if none of your array indexes overflows.

Comment: If you need to accept arrays that exceed your stack size, you'll want to use heap memory, i.e., use dynamic memory allocation with malloc & friends.